# android - controlling IME show search action instead of enter

Tags: android

Hi I'm trying to override IME action to show search on virtual keyboard. My `EditText` is in the control that is placed onto the activity.

Here is what I have:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textColor="@color/main_text_black"
    android:layout_width="247dp" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="38px" />
```

In Code I have this listener set on the `EditText`:

```
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
    if((arg1 == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
        for(OnSearchListener listener : _listeners) {
            listener.OnSearch(view, getSearchString());
        }
    }
    InputMethodManager imm = 
        (InputMethodManager)_context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);

    return false;
}
```

`arg1` always comes back as `0` when I press the enter key, which is "unidentified". I also tried different keyboards like sendMessage and none of them work neither. What's going on?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: basically I already removed this from the control and added it onto an activity and it still wouldn't work. I tried sendMessage too. Nothing! android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"  
   android:inputType="textShortMessage|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine" Its' like IME is disabled altogether or overriden in some settings somewhere. All I did was added the options in the xml and trying see what's being shown. I get same window every time. No changes to the virtual keyboard whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

updated to droid 2.2 and it started working. Horrible bug!

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify android:inputType="text" attribute in xml file.